# Como mostrar erros de conexão em HTMLs com um JSON?

Tags: jquery, json, conexão

Estava desenvolvendo um HTML que acessava um arquivo JSON. Quando, do nada, caiu a internet da minha casa e acabei pensando nessa questão:

- Existe uma maneira de pegar um erro de conexão e avisar o usuário desse erro?

Por exemplo, se der um erro, tipo o `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`, como eu faria para mandar um `alert` avisando o usuário que deu *time-out* na conexão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode descobrir qual tipo de erro foi dado acessando o **textStatus** do `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);`

Eu tirei esse exemplo dessa postagem aqui: [Determine if ajax error is a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543683/determine-if-ajax-error-is-a-timeout)

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "/ajax_json_echo/",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 1000,
    success: function(response) { alert(response); },
    error: function(x, t, m) {
        if(t==="timeout") {
            alert("got timeout");
        } else {
            alert(t);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ok. Funcionou legal aqui. Valeu pela ajuda! :)

Comment: @GabrielPolidoro de nada! Fico feliz em ter ajudado, você pode sinalizar ela como resposta?